# Compare datetimes ignoring time zone

Tags: c#, datetime, timezone

I have timestamps from the *different timezones* and I want to *compare* times from different timezones *ignoring timezone* information. Basically, `9AM` from *one timezone* should be equal to `9AM` from *another timezone* in my case. How should I do this in C# in the most natural way?

```
var dt1 = DateTime.Parse("2022-01-17T18:59:43.0030684+06:00");
var dt2 = DateTime.Parse("2022-01-17T18:59:43.0030684+03:00");

Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Compare(dt1, dt2));
```

It returns `-1` right now, I want something that returns `0`.

Comment: This seems like an odd thing to do. Ignoring the timezone information just makes your comparisons invalid. Those two dates are 3 hours apart....

Comment: why not slice off the offset then call `.Parse`

Comment: @Liam true, but for both of those times, "it is 7pm" in a *human* sense

Comment: True, but the moments in time that they represent are still 3 hours apart.

Comment: @AakashM agreed. It's easy to imagine two people in different time zones comparing what time they wake up in the morning.

Comment: If you are only interested in the time component, you can also have a look at `TimeOnly`, see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timeonly?view=net-6.0

Comment: @Liam it may seem so, but that's what I need to do, I just don't want to give more context than necessary :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
var dt1 = DateTimeOffset.Parse("2022-01-17T18:59:43.0030684+06:00");
var dt2 = DateTimeOffset.Parse("2022-01-17T18:59:43.0030684+03:00");
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Compare(dt1.DateTime, dt2.DateTime));
```

Answer (score 3):

Technically, you can use `DateTimeOffset` instead of `DateTime` in order to compensate (i.e. add) difference of time zones:

**Code:**

```
var dt1 = DateTimeOffset.Parse("2022-01-17T18:59:43.0030684+06:00");
var dt2 = DateTimeOffset.Parse("2022-01-17T18:59:43.0030684+03:00");

Console.WriteLine(DateTimeOffset.Compare(dt1 + dt1.Offset, dt2 + dt2.Offset));
```

**Outcome:** ([fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/b35vlG))

```
0
```